# ChartJS / Chartjs-plugin-annotation How to draw multiple vertical lines using an array?

Tags: jquery, charts, chart.js

I want to create multiple vertical lines by supplying two array, the first called `marketing` which contains dates such as `"2017-09-21"` etc. and an array called `amount` which contains only numbers.

I have created my line chart using ChartJS. The final result should look like this but with multiple lines. [image: Expected chart]

Here is my code so far

```
annotation: {
    drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw',
    annotations: [{
        type: 'line',
        mode: 'vertical',
        scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
        value: marketing,
        borderColor: 'green',
        borderWidth: 1,
        label: {
            enabled: true,
            position: "center",
            content: amount
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Your question is contradictory. Title says **vertical** but in body it's **horizontal**.

Comment: @ɢʀᴜɴᴛ Thanks I corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you have two arrays (`marketing` and `amount`) as such :

```
var marketing = ['2017-08-05', '2017-08-12'];
var amount = [50, 70];
```

You can create/populate the `annotations` array dynamically based on one of those arrays *(marketing/amount)* to draw multiple vertical lines, like so :

```
// populate 'annotations' array dynamically based on 'marketing'
var annotations = marketing.map(function(date, index) {
   return {
      type: 'line',
      id: 'vline' + index,
      mode: 'vertical',
      scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
      value: date,
      borderColor: 'green',
      borderWidth: 1,
      label: {
         enabled: true,
         position: "center",
         content: amount[index]
      }
   }
});
```

see a [**working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/caj89x6L/).

Comment: @ɢʀᴜɴᴛ I tried with this code but not working for this is my code `const testValue = ['0.019', '0.033', '0.305', '0.428', '0.582', '0.826']
    const customGrid = map(testValue, (el) => {
      return {
        type: 'line',
          mode: 'vertical',
          scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
          value: el,
          borderColor: 'green',
          borderWidth: 1
      }
    });`  `annotation: {
        annotations: customGrid
      },`

Comment: Do we have the possibility to define the height of the line ? For instance the height if the vertical line shall be y value 4?

Comment: I want to add another annotations array with different configuration. How i do that

Comment: The example is not using a time x axis. So x values are like category names and not like a real time line. How do I add annotations when the x axis is a time line?